# Archivo nuevo no se crea

Tags: python, csv

El código que está en el link debería tomar un archivo CSV, hacer unas modificaciones y guardar las mismas en otro archivo.

El problema es que no está creando el archivo nuevo.

```
archivo = open("C:\Curso Python\base_de_datos_de_clientes.csv",'r')
copia= open("C:\Curso Python\Clientes_Nuevo.csv","w",encoding="latin-1")
suma=0
promedio=0.0

archivo_en_lineas = archivo.readlines()

numero_de_clientes = len(archivo_en_lineas)

matriz_de_datos = []

for linea in archivo_en_lineas:
    linea = linea.strip()
    fila = linea.split(";")
    matriz_de_datos.append(fila)

for fila in matriz_de_datos:
        fecha_de_nacimiento=fila[3]
        fecha_de_nacimiento_lista=fecha_de_nacimiento.split('-')
        fila[3] = fecha_de_nacimiento.replace('-','')
        edad=int(fecha_de_nacimiento_lista[0])
        edad2=2022-edad
        fila.append(str(edad2))

for fila in matriz_de_datos:
    valor_rut=fila[0]
    fila[0]=valor_rut.replace('A.!--','')
print(matriz_de_datos)

for fila in range(numero_de_clientes):
                suma=suma+int(matriz_de_datos[fila][8])
        
promedio=suma/numero_de_clientes
print("El promedio de edad de clientes es",promedio)

for fila in archivo:
    copia.write(archivo)

archivo.close() 
copia.close()
```

Comment: Quité todo el código de más, cambié el directorio del archivo final, lo probé y funciona. Es más, veo la parte donde creas los archivos pensando que olvidaste los close pero no. También comprobé si la barra invertida estaba creando un caracter raro. Revisaste bien la carpeta donde lo creas? Estas mirando la carpeta correcta?

Comment: ¿`copia.write(archivo)`? ¿No sera `copia.write(fila)`?

Comment: ".write" guarda texto, no guarda objetos de tipo "file". Osea, como dijo @CandidMoe, pon "write(fila)"

Comment: Buenas tardes. Hice el cambio de copia.write(archivo) a No sera copia.write(fila) pero aun tengo problemas. de todas formas para que lo vean, tengo la base aqui en csv https://github.com/neromerob/mis_codigos/blob/main/database.rar  si lo pueden ejecutar y les funciona tengo que considerar otras opciones. muchas gracias.

Comment: Es que es muy raro que no te funcione. ¿Hiciste lo que propuse de asegurarte de estar viendo la carpeta correcta?

Comment: pude hacer el programa, crea el archivo, solo que ahora lo crea vacío, lo hice en C y también en una capeta en "mis documentos" (colocando \\ en toda la ruta para evitar error) no comprendo porque no guarda los cambios

Comment: `archivo` ya lo has leído con `archivo.readlines()`. Cuando vuelves a leerlo, simplemente no hay nada más.